# Is there a way to apply zoom using the FPVOverlayWidget?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I want to apply zoom on the video streaming directly like in the Litchi app.

Is there a way to do it with the UX SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the camera documentation,  there are varying methods to control camera zoom.

The mobile sdk is included with the ui sdk.